Laravel: how to log all SQL queries and customize it
I am working on a laravel project and need to log all SQL queries in the daily log file and make some customizations. What I have done is modify app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:
public function boot()
{
    if (config('app.log_sql') == true) {
            //记录sql
        DB::listen(function($query) {
            $tmp = str_replace('?', '"'.'%s'.'"', $query->sql);
            $tmp = vsprintf($tmp, $query->bindings);
            $tmp = str_replace("\\","",$tmp);
            Log::info($tmp."\n\n\t");
        });
    }
}

After that, once app.log_sql is true, the SQL queries are recorded in the daily log file. But what I need to do is put the SQL queries log with other logs together. I also need to log for all requests and responses.
I have a middleware file:
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $memory_peak_start = memory_get_peak_usage();

    $response = $next($request);

    $uuid = (string)md5( uniqid() . time());
 
    Log::info('log message', json_encode([
        'request_url' => $request->url(),
        'request_id' => $uuid,
    ]));
    return $response;
}

I need to put the SQL queries log with request_url and request_id together (which means one log record has request_url, request_id and SQL queries). Can you please help me to figure it out? MANY THANKS!

I don't know if you've looked into this, but Laravel has a DB::getQueryLog() that returns an array of recent queries.

@aynber thanks for your comment, what i need is to log all sql queries for every request, I will try this method to see if it would be okay

you can use Telescope to look up SQL queries that are used per request. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/telescope

@aynber i tried this method in the middle file, but no sql array return, i also add         DB::enableQueryLog(); still not work
